# Apple Airpods Bluetooth Paring not working

Tags: bluetooth, release-hera, apple

I cant seem to pair my airpods to OS 5.1 Hera, has anybody else managed? it just spins at pairing then says unable to pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had problems with headphones, the easiest way is to go through `blueman`

For your Airpods I thinks this answer in the Ubuntu StackExchange can Help your [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063582/1013655)

> 1. Set `ControllerMode = bredr` or `ControllerMode = dual` by editing `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file using `sudo nano
>      /etc/bluetooth/main.conf` command (or another text editor of your
>      choice)
> 2. `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`
> 3. Try to pair again.
>
>    By [Alexander](https://askubuntu.com/users/857991/alexander) in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Ah it actually worked, i missed the "sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart" also the ControllerMode = dual was commented out, needed to uncomment instead of adding the line, max volume is just low :( but a start

Comment: glad that it could help you. It must also take into account that it depends on the Bluetooth hardware you used but also the driver. For example my Bluetooth dongle works better under Windows. I still had to put it on a USB port on the front of my tower to make the sound works well, but I can see that the distance is shorter with my headset under Linux.

Comment: I'm going to look into the volume issue and post if I find a solution but for now, airpods are working, and reconnect with zero issues !

Comment: What is the difference between bredr and dual?

Answer (score 0):

I may add to your problem, since it seems like bluetooth in general is crap for me. Airpods never work, but also my ps4 controller, and many other devices that normally should connect seemlessly on any other desktop.

Comment: See my Answer below which also has volume fix

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION TO QUESTION**

[To pair airpods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922860/pairing-apple-airpods-as-headset/1063582#1063582)

[To fix volume issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8dmnfk/airpods_with_ubuntu_1704_too_low_volume/)

So glad I got this working :)